# Counting .csv files based on their first n number of characters

Tags: powershell, filter

I need to write a script that checks the first 3 to say 5 characters of a .csv file, then count those files and report the characters with the corresponding count.

I already have a few methods to do the simpler tasks. I've used a filter before to only select certain .csvs, using this:

`Get-ChildItem C:\path -Recurse -Filter *.csv | Where {$_.Name -match 'NNN'}`

I also use this to count the number of csvs in that corresponding location:

`(Get-ChildItem C:\path -Recurse -Filter *.csv | Measure-Object).Count`

How can I run a scan through a folder with say 3 random titles for the csv? Say they're RUNxxxxxxxx.csv, FUNxxxxxxx.csv, and TUNxxxxxxx.csv.

Edit: Let me explain more; basically, the example csvs I have above would be completely random, so it'd need to recognize those first 3 are different and only count those.

I'm not sure if a prompt inputting these would do any. The values are known, just different week to week (which is when this would be run;every week)

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `-Include RUNxxxxxxxx.csv, FUNxxxxxxx.csv, and TUNxxxxxxx.csv` with `Get-ChildItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a calculated property to add the desired part as additional property to be able to work with it?

```
$PatternList = 
'run',
'fun',
'tun'


Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csv | 
Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Part'; Expression={($_.Name).substring(0,3)}},* |
Where-Object -Property Part -In -Value $PatternList |
Group-Object -Property Part
```

Comment: How could I use this with random beginnings? They won't always be run....,fun...., or tun.... ; those were examples to represent a random name.

Comment: After looking into the csvs more, it seems as the first 3 letters aren't completely random. It may just differ from week to week. For example, one week contains 'NNN' and 'XXX" then the next might be 'NNN' and 'YYY'. Would storing every known 3 letter pattern like above be the correct way to do this? Or could a dialog box work for user input?

Comment: I'm leaning towards more automatic. Would it be possible to use if else statements to count? I could include all known patterns and possibly just run that.

Comment: If the 3 letter pattern exists within the folder, then count. If not, then don't count.

Comment: Would there we a way to then use those counts individually? Say 'NNN' count is 5 and 'XXX' is 6. Can I use them separately?

Comment: I don't know how to use that value in the count row that powershell spits out. I still recently new to powershell.

Comment: And I don't know what you expect. Whatfor or how do you want to use it? You can use the output objects and their properties by their names if you need them individually.  Please add this requirement to your question - not as comment.  Regardless of that you may do a step back and start with  learning the very basics of PowerShell first.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using the where-object filter combining three or statements which finds anything starting with the three letters you want and a wild card after.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\path -Recurse -Filter *.csv | Where {$_.Name -like "RUN*" -or $_.Name -like "Fun*" -or $_.Name -like "TUN*"}
```

You could also use the get-childitem -filter to accomplish this instead of searching for all .csv files and then use where-object.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\path -Recurse -Include "fUN*.csv","RUN*.csv","Tun*.csv"
```

Comment: Yes, I've used that before. I'm wondering if there's a way to check the first 3, read those, then count all others like it.